# What is the "officially" recommended way of installing Haskell from source?

Tags: haskell

How does one install Haskell from source (on Red Hat) now?

The current page has broken links and conflicting advice.

From http://www.haskell.org/platform/linux.html

> Get and install GHC 7.6.3 prior to building the platform

From http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3

> For most users, we recommend installing the Haskell Platform instead of GHC. The current Haskell Platform release includes a recent GHC release as well as some other tools (such as cabal), and a larger set of libraries that are known to work together.

(the link to cabal-install is broken).

Comment: The recommended way to install GHC is by installing the [Haskell Platform](http://www.haskell.org/platform/). Doesn't that satisfy your needs?

Comment: I just want to install pandoc on RedHat without all the hassle merely to use ipython nbcovert. Going to Haskell Platform -> Linux -> Fedora seems to lead to a bunch of circular references. I tried a few .rpm but RedHat has poor support for almost everything.

Comment: Can you install `pandoc` directly from your package manager's repositories?  Why do you need to compile it yourself?

Comment: RedHat's yum failed to find anything or suggest anything for pandoc and I failed to care enough to find the "correct" repo to add to make this work. I would say I give yum about 5 minutes of reading and then I try to compile myself and usually succeed just as quickly. If you have a suggestion of how to use yum to install pandoc on RedHat I am listening.

Comment: It looks like you got something working for yourself by compiling from source, but for future reference `pandoc` is available from the standard [EPEL repo](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The broken link should be pointing to http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Cabal-Install instead.  If you want to install from source, you're first going to have to compile and install GHC from source, then you can install the Haskell Platform from its source.

I'm not really sure what conflicting information you're seeing, if you want to build from source you have to install GHC first.  Alternatively, you can just install the Haskell Platform from the distributable (might not be possible on Red Hat) and it'll install GHC for you.  Both are pretty straightforward.

Comment: This indeed worked. Start with GHC and simply build you're way up through Haskell and Cabal to pandoc following the READMEs. Maybe 30 minutes including build time.